# How to create a custom text box control in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

I'm trying to create a Silverlight custom text box. I want the text box's background to change based on the value in it. It becomes red if it is under zero and it return white when it is more than zero.

How can I achieve that ?

I've created a simple class and a user control but I can't achieve the target yet. Here is the code

Custom Textbox code

```
public class CustomTB: TextBox
{
    protected override void OnTextInputUpdate(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        double val;
        if (double.TryParse(e.Text, out val))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

User Control C# code

```
    public partial class AlabdCustomTextBox : UserControl
    {
    public AlabdCustomTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void CustomTB_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double value;
        if (double.Parse(customTB.Text) < 0)
        {
            customTB.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }

        else
        {
            customTB.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }

        BindingExpression binding = this.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
        if (null != binding)
        {
            binding.UpdateSource();
        }
    }
}
```

User Control XAML Code

```
 <cc:CustomTB Name="customTB" Background="White" Text="{Binding    Screen.ComparisonItems.SelectedItem.AdditionalCost}" TextChanged="CustomTB_TextChanged" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a standard `TextBox`.

Just bind the background colour to the text's length through a converter that returns `red` when the value is less than zero and `white` the rest of the time.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
        return System.Windows.Media.Color.White;

    if ((int)value < 0)
        return System.Windows.Media.Color.Red;

    return System.Windows.Media.Color.White;
}
```

Then in the XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
         Background="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}" />
```

Where `myConverter` is the converter you created above.

This will run the converter and change the background colour as appropriate when the value changes - when the text box loses focus.

If you want to do this check on every key stroke you can either add a "KeyUp" handler to every single text box or just subclass the `TextBox` class and add a override for the `OnKeyDown` method:

```
class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        decimal value = 0;
        if (Decimal.TryParse(this.Text, out value))
        {
            if (value < 0)
            {
                this.Background = System.Windows.Media.Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                this.Background = System.Windows.Media.Color.White;
            }
        }
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

You would then use this instead of the standard TextBox, you don't need another `UserControl` layer:

```
<MyControls:MyTextBox Text={Binding Value, Mode TwoWay}"/>
```